# Why is my variable showing NULL?

Tags: php, oop

So I have a users class with the following code:

```
class User {
private $ID;
private $userLevel;
private $username = "";
private $password = "";
private $lastHit;

/**
 * Sets the username.
 * @param string $username - The username you want to change too.
 * @return string - Returns the username which was set.
 */
public function setUsername($username) {
    return $this->username = $username;
}
/**
 * Sets the password.
 * @param string $password - The password you want to change too.
 * @return string - Returns the password which was set.
 */
public function setPassword($password) {
    return $this->password = $password;
}
/**
 * Sets the ID.
 * @param int $ID - The ID you want to change too.
 * @return int - Returns the ID which was set.
 */
public function setID($ID) {
    return $this->ID = $ID;
}
/**
 * Sets the User Level.
 * @param int $userLevel - The User Level you want to change too.
 * @return int - Returns the User Level which was set.
 */ 
public function setUserLevel($userLevel) {
    return $this->userLevel = $userLevel;
}
/**
 * Returns the username stored in $username.
 * @return string - Returns the username stored in $username.
 */
public function getUsername() {
    return $this->username;
}
/**
 * Returns the password stored in $password.
 * @return string - Returns the password which has been set.
 */
public function getPassword() {
    return $this->password;
}
/**
 * Returns the ID stored in $ID.
 * @return int - Returns the ID which has been set.
 */
public function getID() {
    return $this->ID;
}
/**
 * Returns the User Level stored in $userLevel.
 * @return int - Returns the User Level which has been set.
 */
public function getUserLevel() {
    return $this->userLevel;
}
/**
 * Returns the Last Hit stored in $lastHit.
 * @return date - Returns the time of the users last hit.
 */
public function getLastHit() {
    return $this->lastHit;
}
/**
 * Checks if the provided $username and $password exist in `users` table in DB. Used for login authentication.
 * @global object $PDO - Connection for DB.
 * @param string $username - The username which you would like to check.
 * @param string $password - The password which you would like to check.
 * @param error\Error $errors - Object class for the Error class.
 * @return int - Returns 1 if user is found 0 if not.
 */
public function checkLogin(error\Error $errors, $username, $password) {
    global $PDO;

    $checkUser = $PDO->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE Username=? AND Password=?");
    $checkUser->bindParam(1, $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $checkUser->bindParam(2, $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $checkUser->execute();
    $rowCount = $checkUser->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

    if($rowCount[0] == 1) {
        session_start();

        $selectLoggedInUser = $PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE Username=?");
        $selectLoggedInUser->bindParam(1, $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $selectLoggedInUser->execute();
        $results = $selectLoggedInUser->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        $this->setID($results->ID);
        $this->setUserLevel($results->User_Level);
        $this->setUsername($results->Username);

        $_SESSION['ID'] = $this->getID();
        $_SESSION['User_Level'] = $this->getUserLevel();
        $_SESSION['Username'] = $this->getUsername();
        $_SESSION['Online'] = 1;
        $this->lastHit = $_SESSION['Last_Hit'] = date('g:i:s A');

        return 1;
    } else {
        $errors->setError("Username or Password incorrect.");
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Then I have a file which sets the details so a login page:

```
<?php
        if($users->checkLogin($errors, $username, $password) == 1) {
            $functions->message("You have logged in!", "success");
            $functions->redirect('loggedIn', 'timed', 3);
        } else {
            $functions->message($errors->getError(), "errors");
        }
    }
}
```

Yet when I try access the variable in a page called loggedIn.php which calls after the user has logged in nothing shows up. So I did var_dump(); and NULL is being passed through when I call for the getter. However if I call directly through the session the value shows.

loggedIn.php

```
<?php

session_start();

/**
 * @author Script47
 * @copyright (c) 2014, Script47
 * @version 1.0
 */

include 'functions/Functions.php';
include 'functions/User.php';
include 'functions/Module.php';
include 'functions/Error.php';
include 'config/pdo.config.php';

$functions = new core\Functions();
$users = new User();
$modules = new module\Module();
$errors = new error\Error();

define('MODULE_NAME', 'Login');
define('MODULE_VERSION', '1.0');

$modules->setModuleName('Login');
$modules->setModuleVersion(1.0);
$modules->setModuleTitle();

if($users->checkSessionExist() == 2) {
    $errors->setError("You need to be logged in to view this page.");
    $functions->message($errors->getError(), "error");
    return;
}

echo '<h1>Auth Page</h1>';

echo var_dump($users->getID());

$functions->lineBreak();

echo $users->getUsername();

$functions->lineBreak();

echo $users->getLastHit();
```

I've tried debugging but with no avail I turned to StackOverFlow, I looked on Google but could not find a solution.

Comment: That's a lot of code. You couldn't narrow it down any more than that?

Comment: Reduce it to a single form input, and see if you can reproduce it. Often when you will discover the answer when you try to create the Minimum Working Example.

Comment: @JohnConde I did narrow it down, then I thought people would like to see it all. So I put it all. I shall narrow down again.

Comment: Which particular variable?

Comment: @Script47 we _never_ want to see it all. It isn't clear here which variable is at issue. Trim it away to just where the variable is defined, anything that modifies it, and whatever calls it. Keep relevant things like `session_start()` in place too.

Comment: @Rahul This part (The getters don't work): echo '<h1>Auth Page</h1>';

echo var_dump($users->getID());

$functions->lineBreak();

echo $users->getUsername();

$functions->lineBreak();

echo $users->getLastHit();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your script (loggedIn.php) you also have the line `$users = new User();`. This line overwrites the users object that was initialized in the include file with a new, empty object.

So, remove this line from `loggedIn.php` (*not* from the other file!) and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks you this works, yet how would I use functions from users file if I don't instantiate it in loggedInt.php?

Comment: You already instantiate it in the include file, right? So you can use the methods of that instance.

Comment: So even in a separate file I would be able to call it? If I'm not misunderstanding what you mean, do you mean statically calling it? If not could you please show a small example?

Comment: Well, you've completely changed the second code snippet now, but before, there was a global $users variable being initializes there. But you also said my answer works, so I don't really understand what problem remains now.